# Run specific sudo commands in wildfly

Tags: tomcat, servlets, command, wildfly, sudo

I want to run specific commands with sudo in my servlet in wildfly.

I know that I can run specific commands with the tomcat user:

```
tomcat ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/jur/virt.sh, /home/jur/createdisk.sh
```

I tried with the user 'widlfly' but that doesn't work.
Now I don't know what the name of the wildfly user is. My servlet can't run the commands with sudo.

In my servlet I have this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sudo /home/jur/createdisk.sh " + parameter);
```

wildfly gives the error: *"Java.io.IOExeption: Cannot run program "sudo /home/jur/createdisk.sh parameter": error=2, No such file or directory"*

When I do the same in the terminal with the user 'jur', it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructor of ProcessBuilder class takes multiple arguments and the first one needs to be program name and following are arguments of the program.

For example calling `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls -l")` will give same error as you mentioned, but calling `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "-l")` is going to be successful.

Correct syntax in your case should be
`ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "/home/jur/createdisk.sh", parameter);`